# Libgdx XML access child inside child

Tags: xml, libgdx

I have an xml file like this:

```
<main>
    <zone id="A1">
        <area id="house">
            <sprite>test.jpg</sprite>
            <location x="33" y="345"/>
            <sprite>test.jpg</sprite>
            <location x="33" y="345"/>
            <text id="1">text example</text>
            <text id="2">text example</text>
            <text id="3">text example</text>
            <text id="4">text example</text>
            <text id="5">text example</text>
            <text id="6">text example</text>
            <text id="7">text example</text>
            <text id="8">text example</text>
            <text id="9">text example</text>
            <text id="10">text example</text>
        </area>
    </zone>
    <zone id="A2">
        <area id="house">
            <sprite>test2.jpg</sprite>
            <location x="32" y="11"/>
            <text id="1">text example</text>
            <text id="2">text example</text>
            <text id="3">text example</text>
        </area>
    </zone>
</main>
```

I have **main** as root element, 2 child elements called **zone**, with different id's and inside the zone element there is another element called **area** with different id's. All data I want to read is inside the area element.
I need to create a function with two parameters `zoneId` and `areaId` to read a specific area info and return it as an array or an object.

Comment: soory for the bad english

Comment: Please, include xml file structure into your question.

Comment: I post a link with the xml

Comment: Yes, I see, but in a long perspective that link will be broken and your question will be incomplete. Take a look at [Complete part](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your question:

```
private void readXml(String zoneToFind, String areaToFind) {
    XmlReader reader = new XmlReader();
    try {
        XmlReader.Element root = reader.parse(Gdx.files.internal("test.xml"));
        Array<XmlReader.Element> zones = root.getChildrenByName("zone");
        for (XmlReader.Element zone : zones) {
            if (zoneToFind.equals(zone.getAttribute("id"))) {
                Array<XmlReader.Element> areas = zone.getChildrenByName("area");
                for (XmlReader.Element area : areas) {
                    if (areaToFind.equals(area.getAttribute("id"))) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < area.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            XmlReader.Element child = area.getChild(i);
                            child.getName();
                            child.getText();
                            child.getAttributes();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // proper exception handling
    }

}
```

Explanation:

1. First of all you should get the root of xml file via

   XmlReader.Element root = reader.parse(Gdx.files.internal("test.xml"));

*`test.xml` should be located in Android asset folder*

2. Then you iterate through all zones children until you find a match. When the match is found we know that the next element we get is area, so we iterate again until we find a match to area.

**Note that you should properly handle the situations when there is no match.**

3. Finally, we know that the current area is what we were looking for, so you can iterate through all of its children and do whatever you need. But these three methods should return enough information about the elements:

   ```
   child.getName(); -- name is like sprite, location... 
   child.getText(); -- text is like text example... 
   child.getAttributes(); - attributes are id, x, y...
   ```